# Need to limit the comma(,) entered in textbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, special-characters, limit

I need to place a limit for the number of commas entered in the text area

I tried these links but it dint help

[Limit the number of commas in a TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842897/limit-the-number-of-commas-in-a-textbox)

[The comma in the textBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54589252/the-comma-in-the-textbox)

Iam using php. Is it possible to implement php or javascript here.

Comment: What language are you trying to achieve this in?

Comment: Iam trying to achieve it using php or javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wait for DOMContentLoaded event, and afterwards bind the textarea with a callback for the "input" event:

```js
const MAX_COMMAS = 3;
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    let textarea = document.getElementById('textbox');

    textarea.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
        let matchCommas = this.value.match(/,/g);

        if (Array.isArray(matchCommas) && matchCommas.length > MAX_COMMAS) {
            this.value = this.value.substring(0, this.value.length - 1); // remove the last comma
            alert("MAX COMMAS EXCEEDED!");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<textarea id="textbox" cols="40" rows="4"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<textarea id="textarea" rows="20"></textarea>
```

JavaScript:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
var maxCommas = 5;

var filterCommas = function(event) {
    var textCommas = this.value.match(/[,]/g);
  if(textCommas.length >= maxCommas && event.key === ',') {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  } 
}

textarea.onkeydown = filterCommas;
textarea.onkeypress = filterCommas;
textarea.onchange = filterCommas;`
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xL04qb8c/2/

Comment: Just so you know someone could still inject commas straight into the textarea and the JavaScript would be rendered useless. To be 100% sure you should check the the data with PHP.

`<?php
$maxCommas = 5;
$theString = "test12345,s asdf,,asdf , sdaf , ,sadfsdafsda ,dfdf, lkjhlkjhkjlhj";
$arr = preg_split('/,/', $theString);
echo implode(',', array_slice($arr, 0, $maxCommas)) . implode('', array_slice($arr, $maxCommas+1, count($arr)));`